# Python closures and variable lookup

Tags: python, closures

The following code works as intended:

```
def f():
    def g():
        print(a)
    a = 42
    return g
f()()
```

`g` loads `a` from its closure and all is well.

Now this snippet fails horribly with `UnboundLocalError`.

```
def f():
    def g():
        print(a)
        a = 43
    a = 42
    return g
f()()
```

Looking at the `dis`, the first code calls `LOAD_CLOSURE` and the second does not. Taking this into consideration it is obvious why the error is raised. The question however is this:

**How does python know when to draw a variable from the closure or from the local scope? (Considering that `print(a)` precedes `a = 43`.)**

**Is this decision taken at compile time? (Well, looks like it, considering that `print(a)` precedes `a = 43`)**

This post is not about the `nonlocal` or `global` keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the absence of `nonlocal` or `global` declarations, Python decides whether a variable is local at bytecode compilation time by checking the function for assignments to the variable. Since the second example assigns to `a` in `g`, `a` is local to `g` in that version.

Comment: yep it's just a simple static check.

Comment: Does this mean, that during compilation, the compiler keeps track of (A) which variables are accessed, and (B) which variables are assigned in each scope, and if there are elements in (A) which are not in (B), it escalates the lookup?